# How to restore iTerm2 tabs in the same directory

Tags: session, iterm2, iterm

I would like to restore iTerm2 tabs in their own directories as they were when iTerm2 was closed. For instance, I have 10 tabs, in each tab I have different directories. Now, when I close iTerm2 and re-open it, it will start all 10 tabs, but all of them will point to my home area. My question is how to restore session where each tab will be restored in its own directory where it was closed.

Comment: I have the same issue. Spent a lot of time searching around and have not figured out how to fix this. iTerm might not be capable of this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here: https://iterm2.com/documentation-restoration.html

Copy-pasted answer:

- You must turn off System Prefs > General > Close windows when quitting an app. For more information on system window restoration, please see Apple's docs.
- You must set Prefs > General > Startup to Use system window restoration settings.
- Force quitting iTerm2, causing it to crash, or upgrading it when prompted should restore your sessions. NOTE: Quitting iTerm2 with Cmd-Q will terminate your jobs and they won't be restored. There is an advanced preference to change this behavior, though.
- You can toggle this feature with Prefs>Advanced>Enable session restoration., but you must restart iTerm2 after changing this setting.
- A session that has had only its window contents restored and not the running processes will get a reverse video Session Restored banner. A properly restored session will pick up right where you left it.
- If you reboot, your jobs will terminate and not be restored. The window contents should be restored.